# How is "per se" used?

Tags: meaning

**per se**

These are the meanings I have found for *per se*; by itself, by himself, by herself, basically ...

Does that mean the following sentences are correct?

> 1. *you should not have let him go per se (by himself)*.
> 2. *per se (basically) the color of it is blue.*
> 3. *you will have to submit that tomorrow per se (itself)*

Comment: Please don't ask two completely unrelated questions together. Edit one of them out and ask it separately.

Comment: The OP does not seem to have understood the expression 'per se' in the first place. 

Comment: As for _per se,_ none of those examples are quite right, although the second one is closest. It does **not** mean "alone" in the literal sense. The meaning is closer to "as such" or "**in** itself."

Comment: okay I have edited one question out!

Comment: Still a GR: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/per_se and none of your examples are using it correctly

Comment: what is GR?! and the thing is that I can understand what the meaning of per se is, like _by itself_, But when I try to replace literally _by itself_ with per se, it comes out wrong and in the wiki I read _The law makes drunk driving illegal per se._ what does per se even means here? why would some one say _the law by itself_?

Comment: Voted to leave open. OP is asking for an explanation - more than is available from a dictionary.

Comment: @rps GR = General Reference, i.e. when someone thinks you can easily look the answer up in a dictionary. On this occasion, I disagree for the reason given in my other comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some further definitions:

> [Chambers](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=per%20se&title=21st&sourceid=Mozilla-search)
>   **per se *adverb***
>   in itself; intrinsically • *not valuable per se*.
>   **ETYMOLOGY**: 16c: Latin, meaning 'through itself'.
>
> **intrinsic *adj***
>   1. belonging to something or someone as an inherent and essential part of their nature.  > 2. [not relevant]
>   **intrinsically *adverb***.
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/per-se?q=per%20se) (ODO)
>   ***adverb***
>   by or in itself or themselves; intrinsically: *it is not these facts per se that are important*
>
> [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/per+se)
>   **per se** *adverb* 
>   by, of, for, or in itself; intrinsically: *This candidate is not a pacifist per se, but he is in favor of peaceful solutions when practicable.*
>   ***Synonyms***: innately, inherently, indigenously, fundamentally.
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/per+se)
>   **per se**
>   ***adverb***
>   by, of, or in itself or oneself or themselves : as such : intrinsically
>   ***adjective***
>   being such inherently, clearly, or as a matter of law
>
> ***intrinsic** adj*
>   1a. belonging to the essential nature or constitution of a thing  
>   [other definitions not relevant]
>
> [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/per%20se)
>   **per se** ***adverb***
>   by, of, or in itself — used to indicate that something is being considered by itself and not along with other things ▪ *She feels that there is nothing wrong with gambling per se, but she thinks that it should be done in moderation.*

One word that carries through most of those definitions is **intrinsic, intrinsically**, and I think that is probably the best synonym, but look also at the other synonyms listed. I think another particularly helpful definition of **intrinsically** is *belonging to the essential nature or constitution of a thing*.

Looking at some of the examples given above:

> *not valuable per se*

An item may not be *instrinsically* valuable - it may not be worth a lot of money, or would not sell for much - but it may be valuable to the owner, perhaps because of memories associated with it, or because it has been passed down through the family, etc.

> *it is not these facts per se that are important*

The facts *on their own* may not be important - but taken together with other information, they then become important.

> *This candidate is not a pacifist per se, but he is in favor of peaceful solutions when practicable.*

He is not a pacifist *just as a basic principle*, or *just because he has a fundamental belief that war is wrong* - but he does believe that peaceful solutions should be used whenever possible.

> *She feels that there is nothing wrong with gambling per se, but she thinks that it should be done in moderation.*

She thinks that there is nothing *fundamentally* wrong *in principle* with gambling - or, nothing *intrinsically* wrong with gambling - or, nothing wrong with gambling *in itself* - and the implication is that it's all the other things associated with gambling (e.g. getting addicted to it; spending lots of money) that are wrong.

Comment: so _per se_ refers to the basic nature of the noun/verb rather than  the noun/verb itself?

Comment: I think I probably agree, but I'm not entirely sure what you mean(!) I would say it refers to the *underlying nature* of the item/action without any 'enhancement', 'modification', or other factors that may sometimes be associated with it in people's minds.